# Auto delete old Sent mail from IMAP sent folder on ipad/ipod

Tags: ios, imap

Using an IMAP email account there is an option to delete "Deleted Messages" : "Remove after one week". I want to do the same with Sent Mail since I CC: all sent-mail to my inbox and it is stored on my main computer.

But I can't find a setting in iOS to auto delete Sent Mail after a certain time (but it exist on OSX).   Is it okay to set my "Sent Mailbox" to the same "Trash" folder as my "Deleted Mailbox" in the "Mail Behaviors"?  Will all mail then be deleted after a week?  Or what is the right way to handle this?

Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars 
Account > Advanced

http://tutorials.bluehost.com/help_media/iphone_imap_advanced.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The mailboxes in iOS will, for the most part tend to themselves. The mailstore isn't permanent, and if the system needs more room, it will purge the local copies of older messages from the local store. The sent box will also *sync* with the Sent mailbox on the IMAP server, so if that mailbox is being purged, the messages will disappear from your local store.

Bottom line, unless you have a very specific reason to want those messages deleted *right now*, you don't need to worry about it. Your iPhone isn't going to "fill up" with sent messages.